# Angular ng-repeat and Bootstrap column not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `ng-repeat` that is displaying a list of items. I want them to be a col width of 2

This is the `index.html` body

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="games">
<head>
    <title>Games</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/fontello.css">
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app/app.js"></script>

    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body ng-controller="gamesCtrl">
    <a ui-sref="games">Games</a>
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div ui-view></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the HTML I am pulling for the `ui-view`

list.html

```
<div ng-repeat="game in games">
    <div ng-class="col-xs-2">
        {{ game.title }}
        <img src="{{game.thumbnailUrl100}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's happening though is its just stacking everything on top of each another and not putting it next to each other.

Here is the inspect element code

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- uiView:  -->
    <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
        <!-- ngRepeat: game in games -->
        <div ng-repeat="game in games" class="ng-scope">
        <div class="ng-binding">Cut The Rope</div>
        <img src="https://az680633.vo.msecnd.net/thumbnail/40071/100/40071.png">
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: game in games -->
    <div ng-repeat="game in games" class="ng-scope">
        <div class="ng-binding">Cut The Rope: Time Travel</div>
        <img src="https://az680633.vo.msecnd.net/thumbnail/40072/100/40072.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Just incase something else is wrong here is the js

```
angular.module('games', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    //take out #
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('games', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "/static/app/list.html",
            controller: 'gamesCtrl'
        })
})

.controller('gamesCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'gamesFactory',
    function($scope, $state, gamesFactory) {
         $scope.$state = $state;
         $scope.games = null;

         function init() {
           gamesFactory.getGames().success(function(games) {
             $scope.games = games.data;
             console.log($scope.games.data)
           });

         }
         init();
    }
])

.factory('gamesFactory', function($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.getGames = function() {
        return $http.get('/games.json');
    };
    return factory;
});
```

Comment: This should work. Is your bootstrap CSS library properly added to HTML?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal yes it is, I went ahead and updated to show all the depencies

Comment: Oh, got your problem. `ng-class` expect an expression so you should pass the string to it.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal updated it to just class and it still is just not even acknowleding the existance of a col div.

Comment: Oh! Can you please paste your generated HTML markup by inspecting element in browser

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal updated with inspect element

Comment: Somethings not right w/the code you're showing. Compare the output from inspecting the HTML with your `ng-repeat`. The inspected HTML  shows that the game title is wrapped in a div. In your ng-repeat the title is not wrapped in a div. That doesn't seem to make sense, are you sure you're editing the right template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-class` expects an expression. Change your markup like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="game in games">
    <div ng-class="'col-xs-2'">
        {{ game.title }}
        <img src="{{game.thumbnailUrl100}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Tried this and it's still not working.. Still not even showing the col-xs-2, it instead just shows the class of that div to be ng-scope

Comment: That's weird. Your generated HTML is totally different than what is in your code. Is there any response interceptor which is processing the HTML?

Comment: Alos, I'm seeing two `<meta>` elements. Although that should not cause any problem but can you please remove it.

Comment: Removed, I also added the js just incase I messed something else up.  Still very confused as to why its doing this..

Comment: Okay, don't loose hope..:-) Just to confirm if we are editing the correct `list.html` means there is not another `list.html`, can you please add some marker text in your `list.html` and see if the changes are being reflrected on refresh.

Comment: hrmm.. this is weird let me try and restart/clear cache

Comment: Glad you guys got to the bottom of it. @interneteur Just a side note, don't use `ng-class` with a string attribute as shown here. It's not necessary. There is nothing dynamic about the class name you are adding, so you don't need to use Javascript to apply the style. The regular `class` attribute will apply the style for you w/out it.

Comment: Yes, @SunilD. you are write. `ng-class` has it's own usage and not needed in the given example. Also, always use `Ctrl + F5` while developing a web application to avoid the caching issue. Also, there is a setting in the Chrome's developer two bar which disables the cache automatically if the dev tool is opened.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-class` is expecting an Angular expression. In this case, you are giving it the actual CSS class name. Angular tries to evaluate that as an expression, which results in undefined (or null or the empty string).

Since you don't need to do anything but apply the class name here, just use the regular `class` attribute instead of `ng-class`:

```
<div ng-repeat="game in games">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    {{ game.title }}
    <img src="{{game.thumbnailUrl100}}"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this, still expanding the entire div, whats odd is that the actual col-xs-2 doesn't even show up.   But the title and img does.  It seems to competly ignore the existance of this class.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `class` instead of `ng-class`? Using the `class` attribute to set the style has nothing to do with Angular, and I see no reason why that would fail ... unless some of your other code is causing it to be removed.

Comment: Also, note as pointed out in an answer by @Dan Crews that you have an extra div. I don't think that extra div is the problem, b/c you never see the class applied. But it can't hurt to remove it.

Comment: I tried using every answer on here, i went ahead and updated with the inspect element output.  Still just stacking ontop of each other

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-src on your image. At the time the page is first rendered, the image size probably can't be determined.

Edit, so the complete html should be:

```
<div ng-repeat="game in games">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        {{ game.title }}
        <img src= "" ng-src="{{game.thumbnailUrl100}}"/>
   </div>
```

As others have pointed out, you shouldn't be using ng-class here.

Comment: Still doesn't do it.  Seems when I do inspect element the the ng repeat element is showing a class of ng-scope and the column is no where to be found..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're repeating the div around the columns, not the columns themselves. Try this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2" ng-repeat="game in games">
    {{ game.title }}
    <img src="{{game.thumbnailUrl100}}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice catch, but to be clear the real issue is the use of `ng-class` in the original code when they just needed the `class` attribute, which you have also corrected.